# Runs on localhost:4000 but not on ec2-ip:4000

Tags: node.js, web, amazon-ec2

I have a nodejs app running on port 4000. I have developed it in my Vagrant box running Ubuntu 16.04 where I am able to curl both http://localhost:4000 and http://vagrant-IP:4000.

However, when I replicate the same set-up on an EC2 instance, I am able to curl only on http://localhost:4000 and not on http://ec2-public-IP:4000.

In both cases server is listening on 0.0.0.0 and CORS is enabled. (Here, vagrant-IP and ec2-public-IP are actual IPv4 addresses). How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you pinged the ec2 ip?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this is a firewall problem - you need to punch a hole through the Amazon firewall to allow the incoming request.

This link should help: [Authorizing Inbound Traffic for Your Linux Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)